# Display a random item from an xml list

Tags: javascript, xml, random

I've been looking all over, and I can't find a clean solution (that I can make sense of).

How can I pull an entry at random from an xml list?

My starting point is as follows (which pulls the latest entry):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var xmlDoc=null;
 if (window.ActiveXObject)
 {// code for IE
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
 }
 if (xmlDoc!=null)
 { 
  xmlDoc.async=false;xmlDoc.load("/folder/file.xml");
  var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
  for (i=0;i<1;i++)
  {
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("@ows_Title")[0]
    .childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }
 }
</script>
```

Any and all suggestions greatly welcomed!

Comment: All over? Really? Don't you just need an iterator and a random number generator? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

Comment: All over, yes. Because that random number generator only helps (as far as can see) if you a) know how many items you have, and b) if you have them listed in a internal array rather than an external file. If you can tell me how to apply the math.random bit i'll be eternally grateful!

Comment: I'd expect `getElementsbyTagName` to return a `NodeList`, which has property `length` and a method `item()` which takes a number.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a clue to progress, and I appreciate it. Unfortunately I have no idea how it translates into code to use. Can i get it to count how many nodes there are, and then pick a random number between 0 and it? If so, please tell me how because i'm in the dark here. Cheers!

Comment: Hmmm on tinkering, i've gotten to replacing "for (i=0;i<1;i++)" with "var i = Math.floor(3*Math.random())" to get a random item where there are 3 in the list. So, is there a way of populating that and replacing the number with the actual number of nodes?

Comment: or do i even need to? if I change 3 to 10000 will that do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

Math.random() will return a number between 0 and 1, and getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList that has a length. Thus,

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)
```

gives you a random index into the NodeList. You can then use this index to call item() to get that node out of the list:

```
var nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("whatever");
var node = nodeList.item(Math.floor(Math.random() * nodeList.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code slightly... to switch "for (i=0;i<1;i++)" with "var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)%x.length);"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var xmlDoc=null;
 if (window.ActiveXObject)
 {// code for IE
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
 }
 if (xmlDoc!=null)
 { 
  xmlDoc.async=false;xmlDoc.load("/folder/file.xml");
  var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
  var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)%x.length);
  {
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("@ows_Title")[0]
    .childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }
 }
</script>
```

Cheers